# Counting records

Tags: php, mysql

How do i **count** records from this query, which satisfy the condition distance. Pls help :)

```
"SELECT
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians({$dane['lat']}) ) * cos( radians(o.lat ) ) * cos( radians(o.lng ) - radians({$dane['lng']}) ) + sin( radians({$dane['lat']}) ) * sin( radians(o.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
,COUNT(*)
FROM ogloszenia o
$where
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING distance<$promien"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians({$dane['lat']}) ) * cos( radians(o.lat ) ) * cos( radians(o.lng ) - radians({$dane['lng']}) ) + sin( radians({$dane['lat']}) ) * sin( radians(o.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
,COUNT(*)
FROM ogloszeniao
where
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING distance<" . $promien . " "
```